# searching for help on solving a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

It has been over 20 years that I finished university.
After that I actually never used complex mathematics skills.

I am trying to make the following calculation:

r^0+r^1+r^2+r^3...+r^n

Where r>0 (e.g. 1.015) and n is an integer > 0

I can of course calculate it by using excel, but I was actually wondering if there is a formula to calculate this series?

Comment: This is $\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [geometric series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) with multiplying ratio $r$, and first term $1$. The sum is given by

$$\sum_{k=0}^n r^k = 1\times \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$